# Is there a compound that contains water as a subcomponent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water

Is there a molecule that contains water chemically bonded to another molecule/element? Could someone provide an example or two?

Comment: That is a hydrate

Comment: Define "chemically bonded". Are you talking about ionic, polar, dipole-dipole, or dispersion forces, or something else?

Comment: I am talking about ionic/covalent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Off the top of my head: Coordination complexes that have water ligated to a (transition) metal atom.

> [image]

[See corresponding Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_aquo_complex)

A familiar example would be (hydrated) copper sulfate $\ce{CuSO4.5H2O}$, which has 4 water molecules ligated to the copper atom. (The fifth water molecule mentioned in the chemical formula is associated copper sulfate via *hydrogen bonds*)

> [image]
>
> [image]

<sub>The picture is sources from the Wikipedia article for copper sulfate, and the [diagram is sourced from this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-chemical-bonds-form-copper-sulfate)</sub>

---

If you're new to the idea of complex ions, [this chemguide article](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/complexions/whatis.html) offers a good intro to the topic.

Comment: Many examples such as this. You can have a look at montmorillonite as well (hydrated sodium calcium aluminium magnesium silicate hydroxide), even if the exact nature of the bond with water is a bit unclear (there is a balance between the bond with hydroxide and the associated water molecules).